# Update different databases offline

Tags: mysql, database, replication, offline

I know this is a specific question that might start a debate, so please bear with me. I think it would be useful for more than one people coming across this situation or something similar. Here's the current situation:

- 3 similar databases online on 3 different servers (mostly same structure)
- All 3 servers have some "shared" tables (by "shared" I mean the same structure and supposedly the same data -- "customers" for this example)

Now let's assume they can't talk to each other to replicate data in real time (blackout for example), and all of these shard tables MUST match IDs (primary keys) AND data, but all 3 already added different "customers" while offline and of course, IDs won't match.

Does anyone can come up with a solution to replicate (AND match IDs) for the tables when they go online again, taking in consideration that probably on all 3 servers "clients" table might have added data to each "customers" table on each server?

The only solution I came up so far is to add another "key" (autoincremental, not PK) and a BIT field for "replicated", When TRUE, assigns a MAX(customer_id) + 1 (performing a MAX() on all "customers" tables) and assign that number to all tables, becoming that the customer_id. The solution seems to work just fine, except if the clients have performed operations on the system and inserted or updated values with that still not "replicated" customer_id.

As always, thanks for your support.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? sql-server <> mysql and the answers will be vastly different.

Comment: I'm working with mySql